# itextsharp: unable to cast from FilteredRenderListener to ITextExtractionStrategy

Tags: itext, extract, area

I want to extract text from a specified pdf area with itextsharp. I know there is an example http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter15/ExtractPageContentArea.cs#l35. The core code is like this:

```
     RenderFilter[] filter = {new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect)};
     ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
     string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i, strategy);
```

However, vs2012 shows me that "cannot convert implicitly from FilteredRenderListener to ITextExtractionStrategy ". I tried to do explicit conversion. But failed. Could anyone help me? Do I use a wrong itextsharp version? Thanks so much!

Comment: Just FYI, Sourceforge has the old SVN repository. iTextSharp is currently on GitHub: http://github.com/itext/itextsharp

Comment: And now I see that we didn't port the ITextSharp examples from SVN to Git, because the directory was not a default SVN directory like `trunk`, `branches` or `tags`. I think I know what to do on Monday morning

Comment: I cannot know the right version of itextSharp from sourceforge. So I just copy the appropriate version of FilteredRenderListener, which herits ITextExtractionStrategy interface, to my project. Now it works. Thanks so much!

Comment: I think it might be a good idea if we removed that repository from Sourceforge once we've checked everything, because Sourceforge has become untrustworthy (read the media) and we put up a notice that people should go to GitHub.

Comment: @juilylian Did my answer solve your question? Or are there any issues left

Comment: My problem has been solved. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your line looks like this:

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter);
```

but the [corresponding lines from the sample](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter15/ExtractPageContentArea.cs#l38) you reference look like this:

```
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy;
...
strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(
    new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), filter
);
```

I.e. the sample uses a `FilteredTextRenderListener` while you only use a `FilteredRenderListener`. The former actually extends the latter to also implement `ITextExtractionStrategy`.

Thus, simply use `FilteredTextRenderListener` instead of `FilteredRenderListener`.